# Articulation points and bridges in a graph

Tags: algorithm, graph, depth-first-search

Today I learned about articulation points and bridges in a graph(basically undirected).

The text from where I read ( a book by steven-halim) says

> When we are in vertex `u` and `v` is its neighbor, then if `dfs_low(v) >=
>   dfs_num(u)` then `u` is a cut vertex.

Whereas ,

> The condition becomes `dfs_low(v) > dfs_num(u)` while checking for
>   bridges.

But I cannot figure out why the equality is gone from the second case(in bridges).
Please help me with this.

PS: `dfs_num(i)` numbers the vertex as seen in dfs.

`dfs_low(i)` tells the lowest numbered vertex reachable from i other than its parent.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Suppose in the situation being considered that u is an articulation point but u-v is not a bridge.  Then there will exist a path from v to u other than via the u-v link; hence a DFS that passes from the biconnected component containing u to that containing v will eventually reach u again, providing for equality in `dfs_low(v) >= dfs_num(u)`.  (The greater-than part of the inequality occurs because u is an articulation point, so a path from v cannot get to lower-numbered vertices without passing through u, and DFS does not retrace such paths.)

But if u-v is also a bridge, there will not exist any other path between v and u than via the bridge u-v.  So the DFS will never reach u again; and all of the `dfs_num` values after the DFS reaches v will be strictly larger than `dfs_num(u)`.

Comment: Thanks.. Your first paragraph looks a bit wrong and confusing to me, but your second paragraph showed me the way to think and I got the reason.